# Why is Langchainrb Vectorsearch Pinecone ask method returning error "unknown keyword: :prompt"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openai-api, pinecone

I've been working on a Langchain/Pinecone integration for a bit here, and this code was previously working for me. It seems to have broke sometime in the past month or so. Here's a stripped down version that I can run via rails runner:

```
begin
  llm_options = { completion_model_name: "gpt-4-1106-preview", chat_completion_model_name: "gpt-4-1106-preview" }   
  llm = Langchain::LLM::OpenAI.new(api_key: ENV["OPENAI_ACCESS_TOKEN"], default_options: llm_options)

  client = Langchain::Vectorsearch::Pinecone.new(api_key: ENV["PINECONE_API_KEY"],
                                                 index_name: "development-topic-test",
                                                 environment: "us-east-1-aws",
                                                 llm: llm)

  result = client.ask(question: "how do you reverse an array in ruby?", namespace: "topic-markets")
  puts result.inspect

rescue => e
  puts "RESCUED: #{e}"
end
```

This results in the output:

```
RESCUED: unknown keyword: :prompt
```

Things I've checked:

- Environment variables are correct
- The environment is correct and the index name exists in my Pinecone environment
- The namespace exists in that Pinecone index
- Also tried GPT model "gpt-4-turbo-preview" -- yielded the same result
- Tried running the same code in a staging environment with different configuration values -- yielded the same result

Any ideas?

If I had to guess, an API method got changed somewhere, and some code has not been updated yet.

Comment: Note: I was on langchainrb gem version 0.9.0 when experiencing this error.

Comment: Add that to the question -- don't bury it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

For anyone out there who comes across this, the answer was as simple as updating the gem(s).

I performed a `bundle update` in my rails app which updated the following gems to:

- langchainrb (0.9.2)
- pinecone (1.0.1)